# Maximum fetal age for legal abortion in the USA?

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws, abortion

Of all the places that permit abortion in the USA, which ones have the maximum fetal age for legal abortion?

Say State A allows abortion when the age of the fetus is less than 20 weeks, and State B for 24 weeks, then the answer is: "State B with 24 weeks".

However, some states allow abortion even after the X weeks in exceptional cases, so I am asking for the limits for regular abortions and also for exceptional abortions.

I am asking this because abortion is highly politicized.

Comment: -1 Does not show research effort. [Limits on abortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortion_in_the_United_States_by_state#Limits_on_abortion)

Comment: It's also important to keep in mind that no ethical doctor would abort a healthy 8 month (or an earlier viable) pregnancy, regardless of the local law. Most of us agree about early and late terms, it's the middle zone that's controversial.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Guttmacher Institute](https://www.guttmacher.org/state-policy/explore/state-policies-later-abortions), only "43 states prohibit some abortions after a certain point in pregnancy." In other words, **there are 7 states where there is no maximum gestinational/fetal age for legal abortion**. Here is a map [from *Business Insider*](https://www.businessinsider.com/latest-point-in-pregnancy-you-can-get-abortion-in-50-states-2019-5) which shows that those 7 states are Alaska, Colorado, New Hampshire, New Jersey,  New Mexico, Washington and Vermont. **There are many other states which have no *specific* age, and only restrict abortion according to the viability of the fetus.** [A more detailed list from KFF.org](https://www.kff.org/womens-health-policy/state-indicator/gestational-limit-abortions/) shows that DC also has no limits in this regard.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I have added to the question to make a difference between regular and exceptional cases. In those 7 states any woman can make abortion without fetus age limits or only the exceptional cases can?

Comment: @JoeJobs My understanding is that some of the states with limits have exceptions to those limits, but "no limits" means no limits. Whatever regulations exist in those states, as far as I can tell, are not specific to later term abortions.